# Create url to MVC resource from console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a console app and mvc project in the same visual studio solution, when console app is executed, a Mail Message is created, and in the message I need to provide a link to another mvc resource which generate a temp url to download a file.

How can I use something like HttpContext.Current.Request.Url to get the Path to he mvc resource from console app?

Answer (score 0):

Since your console app is executed as another instance and your mvc project could be executed under different urls/proxies, you should store base url in the `app.config` file of your console app.

Comment: That means that for my development environment this base url must be localhost and when I pass this to production I must change this value to the url of the site?

Comment: Yes. You can use App.Release.config file to override app parameters for production environment.